# How set MapElements from viewmodel to view use MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, mvvmcross

I have a map in UWP project and i use Xamarin Classic with MVVMCross Framework but i don´t know how set mapElements from viewModel.

this is my project [enter link description here](https://github.com/migueBarrera/XamarinMapSample)

Comment: Check this topic on the xamarin forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19840/binding-pins-on-map-view-to-collection

Comment: this discussion is for xamarin Forms not classic

Comment: I have checked your sample,  You have used native map control rather than forms [map](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) control. Why?

Comment: As your map is UWP native you cannot use it from your ViewModel, you will have to create a DependencyService to be able to configure it at a Core level.